# Apache httpcomponents Server Cookie/Session Handling

Tags: java, apache, session, cookies

I have been playing around with the Apache httpcomponents. I looked at the example found [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpServer.java).

There seems to be a lot of util classes in the lib but I can't find one to handle cookies and/or sessions, can someone point me in the right direction? An example would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched the apcahe mailing list and found this [answer.](http://marc.info/?l=httpclient-users&m=140653900205168&w=2)

In short it has not been implemented as of 2014-07-27

Here is a quote from the answer above, *"... does not support server side authentication and
state / session management out of the box"*.